# how to make query from datetime filed smaller than current datetime

Tags: python, django

in my django website i need to make query based on datetime filed that are smaller than now this is my query in views.py :

```
 meetings=Meeting.objects.filter(date_time__lt=datetime.now()).filter(Q(members_email__icontains=str(request.user.email))|Q(host=request.user))
```

and this is datetime filed in models.py :

```
date_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

but it returns nothing i don't know how to solve this problem
any suggestion?

Comment: That looks fine to me. Are you sure the problem comes from there ? What happens if you just take off the second filter, still the same ? Add more context to your question (where is it located etc...) because it's not really clear.

Comment: have you tried using django's `timezone.now()` than python datetime.now()?